# Word list with learning age

Tags: data-request, english

I'm looking for word databases, mainly in English and Swedish, which contain lists of words associated with the ages where they are typically learned.

WordNet linkage is a big bonus.

Comment: words.sf.net doesn't quite do what you want (it assigns a "level" to each word and is English only), but might be a start.

Answer (score 6):

**English**

1. *Age-of-acquisition ratings for 30,000 English words (2012)*:

- [Springer link](https://link.springer.com/article/10.3758%2Fs13428-012-0210-4)
- [Free access](http://crr.ugent.be/papers/Kuperman%20et%20al%20AoA%20ratings.pdf)
- [List of words](http://crr.ugent.be/papers/AoA_ratings_Kuperman_et_al_BRM.zip)

2. *Age-of-acquisition, imagery, concreteness, familiarity, and ambiguity measures for 1,944 words (1980)*:

- [Springer link](https://link.springer.com/article/10.3758/BF03201693)
- List of words is within the article, but see also 3.

3. Compilation and comparison of many sources *(50,000 words, 2012)*:

- [Description](http://crr.ugent.be/archives/806), also contains links.

**Swedish**

1. *Swedish and English word ratings of
   imageability, familiarity and age of acquisition
   are highly correlated (99 words, mostly nouns, 2015)*:

- [Free access](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/5ADF4BE21E4C653D47351EE7682E99D4/S0332586515000220a.pdf/swedish_and_english_word_ratings_of_imageability_familiarity_and_age_of_acquisition_are_highly_correlated.pdf)
- List of words is within the article

The authors provide bibliography, there are no references to more eleborative lists of Swedish words, but there are references to lists of Norwegian words.

2. *Ratings of age of acquisition of 299 words across 25 languages: Is there a cross-linguistic order of words? (2016)*:

- [Springer link](https://link.springer.com/article/10.3758%2Fs13428-015-0636-6#CR67)
- [List of Swedish words](https://static-content.springer.com/esm/art%3A10.3758%2Fs13428-015-0636-6/MediaObjects/13428_2015_636_MOESM1_ESM.pdf) (starting from page 31)

3. *Wordbank* (710 Swedish words and combinations of sounds)

- [Raw data](http://wordbank.stanford.edu/analyses?name=instrument_data)
- [By-word summary data](http://wordbank.stanford.edu/analyses?name=item_data)
- [Example report](http://mikabr.github.io/aoa-prediction/aoa_estimation.html)

---

According to Kuperman, Stadthagen-Gonzalez and Brysbaert:

```
  English word   AoA   
 ------------- ------- 
  age            4.38
  word           4.42  
  learning       4.44
  list           5.58
  acquisition   13.63
```