# CEFR for English words by level

Tags: language, english

Are there any **open source data** for English words by CEFR level?

I found https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/wordlists/oxford3000-5000 , which categorizes English words based on CEFR level, but it has license.

Comment: Maybe related: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/11862/16193

Answer (score 3):

Cambridge University Press is making the A1-C2 English Vocabulary Profile available free of charge to teachers and educationalists around the world. Go to [EVP Online](https://www.englishprofile.org/wordlists/evp) to access the resource.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this [word lists link](https://www.toe.gr/course/view.php?id=27) is what you are looking for. It is a course with lists of words as pdfs categorized by CEFR levels.

Alternatively, you can use the [EFLLex: A CEFR-graded lexical resource for English as a foreign language](https://cental.uclouvain.be/cefrlex/efllex), which is open sourced but the you still must cite [the original work/ authors](http://www.lrec-conf.org/proceedings/lrec2018/pdf/439.pdf).

Comment: Has license, needs to be open data

Comment: I just added a second option, which seem to be open sourced ;) hope it helps.