# Dataset with French words by CEFR level

Tags: language, french

As a German speaker learning French, I really enjoyed the "Fremdsprachentexte Reclam" books: they are French literature books for German learners, each book has a CEFR level (e.g. B2, C1...), and the words that are deemed complicated to that CEFR level have translations/explanations in the footnote. [B2 example here.](https://www.biderundtanner.ch/detail/ISBN-9783150199961/Ionesco-Eug%C3%A8ne/Rhinoc%C3%A9ros.-La-pi%C3%A8ce-de-th%C3%A9%C3%A2tre-%C2%B7-La-nouvelle?bpmctrl=bpmrownr.1%7Cforeign.209425-79-0-63234)

I find this an amazing reading experience for language learners.

I'm wanting to create an app for this. I would like to see if there's an open database of French words mapped to their CEFR level. I found answers for [English](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/17612/cefr-for-english-words-by-level) and [Swedish](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/11057/word-list-with-learning-age/11862#11862), and I'm sure there' something for French.

Thanks.